# updateItem is not called when scrolling

Tags: javafx-2, tableview, tablecell

I am loading a table from a database to a tableview.
I am using custom CellFactory at specific columns based on their type/value. Basically I need to highlight cells, in columns that are type Float, which are above a threshold.
I see that this works when the tableview is populated first time but when I scroll the table or sort columns the rendering is messed up i.e. not working.
I noticed that the updateItem is not called when I scroll or sort.
How can I make the TableView rendering "correct" regardless of scrolling and sorting?

This is code part I use:

```
                else
            {
                TableColumn col=new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));   
                col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,Float>,ObservableValue<Float>>()
                    {   
                        @Override
                        public ObservableValue<Float> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, Float> param) 
                        {                                                       
                            return new SimpleObjectProperty(param.getValue().get(j));                
                        } 
                    });                     
                col.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<ObservableList, ObservableValue<Float>>, TableCell<ObservableList, Float>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell<ObservableList, Float> call(TableColumn<ObservableList,ObservableValue<Float>> param)
                    {
                        TableCell<ObservableList,Float> cell=new TableCell<ObservableList,Float>()
                        {                                
                            @Override                                
                            public void updateItem(Float item, boolean empty)
                            {                                                                        
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if(item!=null)
                                {                                                                                
                                    if(item>0.5)
                                    {
                                        setText(item.toString());
                                        setTextFill(Color.BLACK);  
                                        setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
                                        setStyle("-fx-background-color:RED");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        setText(item.toString());
                                        setTextFill(Color.BLACK); 
                                    }
                                }
                            }                                
                        };
                        return cell;
                    }                        
            });                       
                table.getColumns().addAll(col);
                col.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.prefWidthProperty().divide(10));
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to implement your logic to correctly handle all cases. E.g. if the cell is reused from a value greater than 0.5 to a value less than 0.5, you never reset the style.

You need

```
@Override                                
public void updateItem(Float item, boolean empty) {                                                                        
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if(item==null) {
        setText(null);
    } else {                                                                                
        setText(item.toString());
        setTextFill(Color.BLACK);  
        if(item>0.5) {
            setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
            setStyle("-fx-background-color:RED");
        } else {
            setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.NORMAL, 12));
            setStyle("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep that did it.. It seems that I dont have good understanding of setSetyle() and setText() methods. Thanks!